rsync: mkstemp failed: Invalid argument (22), stuck on a file, how to fix?
I've run this command:
sudo rsync -ra --stats --human-readable 
--no-owner --no-group  
--info=progress2 
--log-file=/home/myuser/rsync-log.log 
 ~ /media/myuser/1234ABCD/

And I've got this error:
rsync: mkstemp 
"/media/myuser/1234ABCD/myuser/.local/share/Trash/info/.image_2023-05-18T17:55:34.664473264Z-small.png.trashinfo.mBfC8n" 
failed: Invalid argument (22)

It's the second time I'm getting it, the first was when I tried to run without
--no-owner --no-group

it happened on the same file it seems.
The target destination is an external HDD with ntfs filesystem, the source is a Kubuntu home directory on ext4 filesystem.
I'd prefer to keep the destination filesystem ntfs, because I might need to store files there that would need to be accessible from Windows OS.
Also I don't understand why rsync just gets completely stuck at this point, rather than skipping the problem file and moving on?

What is your source filesystem?   I suspect the problem is the colon in the filename.   It should technically be compatible with NTFS, but is probably disallowed to prevent problems when mounting on a Windows machine.

I'd prefer to keep the destination filesystem ntfs, because I might need to store files there that would need to be accessible from Windows OS.

Unfortunately, files with colons (and several other characters) are not accessible to a windows application.   You should exclude such files if you are interested in compatibility.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions for more information.

I see, thank you! Is there a way to make rsync just move on after such a file? Right now it just stops and gets frozen ; (
